# Сохранение выбранного значения

Tags: php, html

Я вот никак не смог найти, как записать значение, выбранное в select в файл на php, в общем пробовал сделать так. В index.php

```
<form action="ok.php" onsubmit="var now=new Date().getTime()/1000; if(now-__pstd<6) return false; __pstd=now;" method="post">
<select name="selected">
  <option>50</option>
  <option>100</option>
  <option>200</option>
  <option>300</option>
  <option>400</option>
  <option>500</option>
  <option>600</option>
  <option>700</option>
  <option>800</option>
  <option>900</option>
  <option>999</option>
</select></form>

<input value="Запрос" type="submit" name="button_login" />

<select name="selected">
  <option>50</option>
  <option>100</option>
  <option>200</option>
  <option>300</option>
  <option>400</option>
  <option>500</option>
  <option>600</option>
  <option>700</option>
  <option>800</option>
  <option>900</option>
  <option>999</option>
</select>

<input value="Запрос" type="submit" name="button_login" />
```

В ok.php

```
<?php
$BASE="base.php";
$p2=$_POST["selected"];
$fd=fopen($BASE,"a+");
fwrite($fd,$info);
fclose($fd);
?>
```

Но он не записывает выбранное значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дык переменная $p2 остается без внимания в Вашем скрипте.